# Having error with C# while connecting to a database

Tags: c#, database

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
       string nationality = myReader.GetString("country");
       cmbnationality.Items.Add(nationality);
    }
}
```

I am having this problem:

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'
```

At the line:

```
string nationality = myReader.GetString("country");
```

Can anyone help me? I am basically trying to populate values in a combobox from my database. "country" is my column name in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetString` takes an int parameter, which is the ordinal of the data you want.  Change it to:

```
string nationality = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("country"));
```

See the documentation for IDataReader.GetString method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getstring.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but can you please explain me what has been done ?

Comment: Your query returns N number of columns; the data reader have methods that let you get data by the order in which the columns appear in your query, which is what `GetString` does.  `GetOrdinal` takes a column name and tells you what ordinal position it ended up in, so that you can in turn use that to call `GetString`.  Really follow the link to the MSDN documentation, it's quite good.

Comment: @YudishNundun Please remember to accept the answer you found most helpful by clicking the check box under the up / down vote buttons.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply because [Reader.GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) expects an `int` as a parameter. You are passing a `string`. If you *have to* pass a string you will have to call it this way :

```
string nationality = myReader.GetString (reader.GetOrdinal("country"));
```

Comment: i need to passe a string because "country" is my column name in the database. :/

Comment: @YudishNundun It's doable. See my answer you just have to add this call

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use GetString is the following

```
string nationality = myReader.GetString (myReader.GetOrdinal("country"));
```

[MSDN - GetOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal.aspx)
[MSDN - GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`GetString` expects an **int** argument, while you are passing a **string**. Do this instead:

```
string nationality = myReader.GetString (myReader.GetOrdinal("country"));
```

Please read the following for details:

[GetOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal.aspx)

[GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx)